# Objective permalink-preferences for a blog

Tags: wordpress, blogs, permalinks

I've created a SPA-website which will serve as my personal blog. I just can't quite decide on a permalink-structure for the blog-posts.

**I realize that this is a subjective question. Therefore I ask whether there are OBJECTIVE reasons to choose either of the following three permalink-formats** (be it from user, SEO or whatever perspective)

My choices are:

**title** http://example.com/blog/post-title

**category/title** http://example.com/blog/tech-stuff/post-title

**year/month/title**
http://example.com/blog/2015/10/post-title

Comment: maybe -> http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**blog/post-title**:
(This is what wiki-How uses)
If your blog contents title won't mixup in future.

**blog/category/post-title**:
If your blog contents is categorized and the post-title in each categories can't mixup in future.

**blog/year/month/post-title**:
If your blog content has to with news, so you Can repeat the same post-title.

**blog/id** or **blog/id/post-title**:
(This is what Stack-Overflow uses)
The (unique) blog id would be used to fetch the blog contents, and the post-title would serve as a variable.